# Whats the simplest way to get a random file from a folder and display it on flask?

Tags: python, file, flask, filesystems

this is what ive tried so far, but it keeps saying the directory was wrong BUT I KNOW IT WAS RIGHT
infact it even printed the file. Heres my code

```py
@app.route('/notok', methods=['GET'])
def asdfasd():
  path = "path has my irl name so i cant show it sorry ):"
  cats = random.choice([
      x for x in os.listdir(path)
      if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
  ])
  print(cats)
  return flask.send_file(cats)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable cats contains only the filename, I believe you need to send the full path to flask.send_file.

```
@app.route('/notok', methods=['GET'])
def asdfasd():
  path='C:/tmp/'
  cats = random.choice([
      x for x in os.listdir(path)
      if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
  ])
  print(cats)
  return(flask.send_file( (os.path.join(path, cats))))
```